# Misleading browser to download instead of open link

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload

My system uploads a file, stores it in a folder. Now I am trying to download this file again.

In my View I use this to pass through the filename of the selected file being downloaded, this works fine

```
@Html.ActionLink("Download", "Download", new { id = item.Attachment.ToString() })
```

This should call this method to start the download using this "id" passed through, however, instead it tries to redirect me to "http://localhost:55349/MyDocumentUps/Download/Resume.pdf". How do I mislead the browser so it would handle it as if it is of a unknown type and instead of opening it downloads it?

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Download")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public FileResult Download(string id)
{
    // return File("~/Content/fileHistory" + id, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
    return new FilePathResult("~/Content/fileHistory" + id, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
}
```

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` in response header.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still learning MVC, what do you mean by setting it in the response header? (What is the response header?) @Xaqron

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");

Comment: where does that go? I cannot seem to find where to put it

Comment: Put it in `OnActionExecuted`

Comment: Im sorry, I seem to be brain dead today, I do not know what I am doing here

Comment: You correctly send the file to browser the problem is browser tries to open it. To prevent this you need to mislead browser so it would handle it as if it is of a unknown type and instead of opening it downloads it.

Comment: So I would add the HttpContext to the method "public FileResult Download(string id)" or into the view where I go to Download? @Xaqron

Comment: I am understanding entirely what you are saying, i am just not fully understanding how to get there